# How to get the Lat/Lon coordinates if I am given a table of the MINxy and MAXxy, so that I can map it out in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, coordinates, latitude-longitude

Right now I have a table that looks a little like this:

[image: MinX MinY MaxX MaxY]

and I have the geographic coordinate system they were mapped in, but I need to display them as the polygons that they are in ArcMap.

Comment: Those values may not be the corner vertices. They look like they describe the bounding box of each polygon. Are all the polygons supposed to be rectangles?

Comment: Some are, but some seem to be points ( as the min and max is the same for both)

Comment: Hi @Logan 
Have a look [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/adding-x-y-coordinate-data-as-a-layer.htm) . It should help you get started.

Comment: Column for Max are identical with min column. Ask provider what you are dealing with.